# Turkish babel and acronym package issue

Tags: babel, acronyms, turkish

When using `babel-turkish` package with package `acronym`, following error is producing.:

> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.  \relax l.9
>   \AC@undonewlabel{acro:GSM}

The code is below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % also latin5
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

In the early nineties, \ac{GSM} was deployed in many European countries. 
\acf{GSM} offered for the first time international roaming for mobile 
subscribers. The \acs{GSM}’s use of \ac{TDMA} as its communication standard was 
debated at length. And every now and then there are big discussion whether 
\ac{CDMA} should have  been chosen over \ac{TDMA}.


\begin{acronym}[TDMA]
 \acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
 \acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
 \acro{NA}[\ensuremath{N_{\mathrm A}}]
 {Number of Avogadro\acroextra{ (see \S\ref{Chem})}}
 \acro{NAD+}[NAD\textsuperscript{+}]{Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide}
 \acro{NUA}{Not Used Acronym}
 \acro{TDMA}{Time Division Multiple Access}
 \acro{UA}{Used Acronym}
 \acro{lox}[\ensuremath{LOX}]{Liquid Oxygen}%
 \acro{lh2}[\ensuremath{LH_2}]{Liquid Hydrogen}%
 \acro{IC}{Integrated Circuit}%
 \acro{BUT}{Block Under Test}%
 \acrodefplural{BUT}{Blocks Under Test}%
 \end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

When I commented out the line `\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}`, everything is OK.
Why are errors caused? Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `acronym` package uses a colon in its internal labels and this conficts with the active colon set up by `babel-turkish`. There's nothing special about the colon, so we can change it into something else, possibly unique. I chose `@@@@`.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % also latin5
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[printonlyused,withpage]{acronym}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\AC@@acro}{:}{@@@@}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\AC@@acro}{:}{@@@@}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\AC@placelabel}{:}{@@@@}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{A}

In the early nineties, \ac{GSM} was deployed in many European countries. 
\acf{GSM} offered for the first time international roaming for mobile 
subscribers. The \acs{GSM}’s use of \ac{TDMA} as its communication standard was 
debated at length. And every now and then there are big discussion whether 
\ac{CDMA} should have  been chosen over \ac{TDMA}.


\begin{acronym}[TDMA]
 \acro{CDMA}{Code Division Multiple Access}
 \acro{GSM}{Global System for Mobile communication}
 \acro{NA}[\ensuremath{N_{\mathrm A}}]
 {Number of Avogadro\acroextra{ (see \S\ref{Chem})}}
 \acro{NAD+}[NAD\textsuperscript{+}]{Nicotinamide Adenine Dinucleotide}
 \acro{NUA}{Not Used Acronym}
 \acro{TDMA}{Time Division Multiple Access}
 \acro{UA}{Used Acronym}
 \acro{lox}[\ensuremath{LOX}]{Liquid Oxygen}%
 \acro{lh2}[\ensuremath{LH_2}]{Liquid Hydrogen}%
 \acro{IC}{Integrated Circuit}%
 \acro{BUT}{Block Under Test}%
 \acrodefplural{BUT}{Blocks Under Test}%
 \end{acronym}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am appreciated.